# jQuery UI Spinner vs input type="number"

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, input, spinner

Could someone show me how to use jQuery UI Spinner I'd like to replace this.

input type ="number" is useless in some browsers.

```
input type="number"  class="slider" pattern="[0-9]*" value="1"      onchange="drawing.strokeWidth=this.value;     drawing.update(document.getElementById('textInput').value);" min="0" max="40" step="0.5"
```

I've looked at the documentation and just can't wrap my head jQuery..

Comment: There's nothing we can tell you that isn't already shown in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Number is one of the new HTML 5 input types you can use in your html pages, if you run them on a browser version that supports HTML 5.

For jquery spinner, just do the following code:

```
<input id="spinner1" value="1" />
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#spinner1').spinner({ min: 0, max: 40, step: .5 });
</script>
```

I didn't include change event cause I don't know what you're trying to accomplish but checkout the documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/).